# SQL OUTER JOIN column sum returning twice the amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, outer-join

I have a display query that essentially shows stock on hand, on order, and on reserve. It's all fine aside from one part - the Sum of weight and quantity is returning doubled results (only in the case of some amount being on order). I'm sure I've stuffed my joins up, but I can't figure out how.

Current output (with doubled sum):

```
PartNo                     Branch SOHWeight SOHQty ReservedQty SOOEa SOOTo AvgCost type product grade coating finish thickness width length dim1 dim2 Notes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ClassFBR ClassFME ClassFSY AltoQty
-------------------------- ------ --------- ------ ----------- ----- ----- ------- ---- ------- ----- ------- ------ --------- ----- ------ ---- ---- -----
B-254-304---5--40-40-6000  FME    0.33      18     NULL        NULL  1.5   68.7494 B    ANGLE-E 304           NULL   5         NULL  6000   40   40   NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             C        A        B        NULL
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

Expected output is exactly the same, excepting that SOHWeight and SOHQty should be halved (compared to current output)

Notes:

- StockOnHand will have many PackNoID with the same ProductDesc (Part#)
- There can be multiple reservations against the same PackNoID

```
SELECT dbo.tblProducts.PartNo,
       'FME'                                                                                                                                                                                                AS Branch,
       SUM(sOh.Weight)                                                                                                                                                                                      AS SOHWeight,
       SUM(sOh.Quantity)                                                                                                                                                                                    AS SOHQty,
       SUM(dbo.tblReserveDetail.Quantity)                                                                                                                                                                   AS ReservedQty,
       SUM(iif(dbo.tblPurchaseOrderDetail.QuantityUnit = 'TO', NULL, dbo.tblPurchaseOrderDetail.QuantityAmount))                                                                                            AS SOOEa,
       SUM(iif(dbo.tblPurchaseOrderDetail.QuantityUnit = 'TO', dbo.tblPurchaseOrderDetail.QuantityAmount, NULL))                                                                                            AS SOOTo,
       SUM(IIF(SoH.TYPE IN ( 'C', 'SC' ), SoH.COST * SoH.WEIGHT, SoH.COST * SoH.QUANTITY) + PROCESSINGCOST + PROCESSINGFREIGHT + Packaging) / SUM(IIF(SoH.TYPE IN ( 'C', 'SC' ), sOh.weight, sOh.Quantity)) AS AvgCost,
       tblProducts.type,
       tblProducts.product,
       tblProducts.grade,
       tblProducts.coating,
       tblProducts.finish,
       tblProducts.thickness,
       tblProducts.width,
       tblProducts.length,
       tblProducts.dim1,
       tblProducts.dim2,
       tblProducts.Notes,
       tblProducts.ClassFBR,
       tblProducts.ClassFME,
       tblProducts.ClassFSY,
       SUM(IIF(SoH.STATUS = 'SC', SoH.QUANTITY, NULL))                                                                                                                                                      AS AltoQty
FROM   DBO.tblProducts
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblStockOnHand SoH
         ON tblProducts.PartNo = SOH.ProductDesc
            AND SoH.Status IN ( 'I', 'R', 'SC' )
            AND SoH.branch = 'FME'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblReserveDetail
                       RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblReserveHeader
                         ON dbo.tblReserveHeader.ID = dbo.tblReserveDetail.ReserveID
                            AND tblReserveHeader.Completed = 0
                            AND tblReserveHeader.Cancelled = 0
         ON SOH.PACKNOID = tblReserveDetail.PacknoID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPurchaseOrderDetail
         ON dbo.tblPurchaseOrderDetail.ProductDesc = dbo.tblProducts.PartNo
            AND ( dbo.tblPurchaseOrderDetail.Status = N'O'
                   OR dbo.tblPurchaseOrderDetail.Status = N'PD' )
            AND tblPurchaseOrderDetail.branch = 'FME'
GROUP  BY dbo.tblProducts.PartNo,
          tblProducts.type,
          tblProducts.product,
          tblProducts.grade,
          tblProducts.coating,
          tblProducts.finish,
          tblProducts.thickness,
          tblProducts.width,
          tblProducts.length,
          tblProducts.dim1,
          tblProducts.dim2,
          tblProducts.Notes,
          tblProducts.ClassFBR,
          tblProducts.ClassFME,
          tblProducts.ClassFSY
```

Sample data (stripped down):
tblStockOnHand:

```
PackNoID    Status  Weight  Quantity    Cost    ProcessingCost  ProcessingFreight   Packaging   Branch  tblstockonhand.ProductDesc
157220  I   0.165   9   $68.47  $0.00   $2.48   $0.00   FME B-254-304---5--40-40-6000
158620  I   0.01839825  1   $64.27  $0.00   $4.72   $0.00   FSY B-254-304---5--40-40-6000
```

tblPurchaseOrderDetail

```
RecordId    Status  OrderNumber ItemNumber  QuantityAmount  QuantityUnit    PriceQuantity   PriceUnit   Branch  ProductDesc
6976    FD  4441    18  0.25    TO  3790    TO  FBR B-254-304---5--40-40-6000
6936    O   4439    23  0.5 TO  3790    TO  FME B-254-304---5--40-40-6000
6912    FD  4437    1   20  EA  75.96   EA  FSY B-254-304---5--40-40-6000
```

tblPurchaseOrderHeader

```
Status  OrderNumber Branch
O   4439    FME
```

tblProducts

```
PartNo  ClassFBR    ClassFME    ClassFSY    Notes   Type    Product Grade   Finish  Coating Thickness   Width   Length  Dim1    Dim2
B-254-304---5--40-40-6000   C   A   B       B   ANGLE-E 304         5       6000    40  40
```

Comment: please post some sample data and expected result

Comment: Edited OP to show sample data and expected result @Squirrel

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the details the Right Outer Join is suspicious. A right outer join can always be replaced by a left outer join, and the use of both together is likely to produce confusing queries. It's likely that this is the cause of the double results. Try refactoring so that all joins are left outer rather than a combination.

Comment: Tried, same results unfortunately. :(

Comment: @JCro I notice in your final solution below you no longer have a right outer join either.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally nailed it, as far as I can tell, I have to subquery the joins before OUTER joining them, otherwise instead of grouping/summing, they will sum for each record returned. Horrible explanation I know, but here is the end result query. Thanks to anyone who had a look.

```
SELECT  dbo.tblProducts.PartNo, 'FME' AS Branch, SUM(sOh.Weight) AS SOHWeight, SUM(sOh.Quantity) AS SOHQty, 
        ReservedQty, SOOEa,SOOTo
        ,sum(IIF(SoH.TYPE IN ('C','SC'),SoH.COST*SoH.WEIGHT,SoH.COST*SoH.QUANTITY)+soh.PROCESSINGCOST+soh.PROCESSINGFREIGHT+soh.Packaging)/SUM(IIF(SoH.TYPE IN ('C','SC'),sOh.weight,sOh.Quantity)) AS AvgCost
        ,tblProducts.type,tblProducts.product,tblProducts.grade,tblProducts.coating,tblProducts.finish,tblProducts.thickness,tblProducts.width,tblProducts.length,tblProducts.dim1,tblProducts.dim2,tblProducts.Notes,tblProducts.ClassFBR,tblProducts.ClassFME,tblProducts.ClassFSY
        ,SUM(IIF(SoH.STATUS='SC',SoH.QUANTITY,NULL)) AS AltoQty
FROM 
        dbo.tblProducts 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.tblStockOnHand SoH  
        ON tblProducts.PartNo = SOH.ProductDesc AND SoH.Status IN ('I', 'R','SC') AND SoH.branch='FME' 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (SELECT SUM(tblReserveDetail.Quantity) AS ReservedQty, ProductDesc
            FROM dbo.tblReserveDetail INNER JOIN tblReserveHeader ON dbo.tblReserveHeader.ID = dbo.tblReserveDetail.ReserveID INNER JOIN tblStockOnHand ON tblReserveDetail.PacknoID=tblStockOnHand.PackNoID
            WHERE tblReserveHeader.Completed=0 AND tblReserveHeader.Cancelled =0 AND BRANCH='FME'
            GROUP BY ProductDesc) RES
        ON SoH.ProductDesc = RES.ProductDesc 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            (SELECT tblPurchaseOrderDetail.ProductDesc,SUM(iif(QuantityUnit='TO',null,QuantityAmount)) AS SOOEa,SUM(iif(QuantityUnit='TO',QuantityAmount,null)) AS SOOTo 
            FROM tblPurchaseOrderDetail WHERE
            (dbo.tblPurchaseOrderDetail.Status = N'O' OR dbo.tblPurchaseOrderDetail.Status = N'PD') AND tblPurchaseOrderDetail.branch='FME'
            GROUP BY tblPurchaseOrderDetail.ProductDesc) PoD
        ON PoD.ProductDesc = dbo.tblProducts.PartNo
GROUP BY dbo.tblProducts.PartNo,tblProducts.type,tblProducts.product,tblProducts.grade,tblProducts.coating,tblProducts.finish,tblProducts.thickness,tblProducts.width,tblProducts.length,tblProducts.dim1,tblProducts.dim2,tblProducts.Notes,tblProducts.ClassFBR,tblProducts.ClassFME,tblProducts.ClassFSY,SOOEa,SOOTo,ReservedQty
```